# Searching a way to use different variadic functors basing on condition

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, functor

I have a runtime boolean `verbose` that if `false` excludes some prints to stdout.
To fix ideas, consider to have a lot of parts like:

```cpp
void add(const int a, const int b, const bool verbose)
{
    //...
    if(verbose) std::print("{}+{}={}\n", a, b, a+b);
}
```

My goal is to have something like:

```cpp
template<typename F>
void add(const int a, const int b, F print_if_verbose)
{
    //...
    print_if_verbose("{}+{}={}\n", a, b, a+b);
}
```

The motivation is to simplify the code and make it less error prone (forgetting to test `verbose` each print), but also to avoid the various subsystems to be aware of the `verbose` parameter.

My first attempts are ([godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4ca8TWqvK)):

```cpp
template<typename F>
void add(const int a, const int b, F print_if_verbose)
{
    print_if_verbose("{}+{}={}\n", a, b, a+b);
}

int main(const int, const char* const argv[])
{
    const bool verbose = get_verbose_arg(); // runtime boolean

    // This doesn't compile, types are different
    //const auto vprint = verbose ? [](const std::string_view msg, const auto&... args){std::vprint_unicode(msg, std::make_format_args(args...));}
    //                            : [](const std::string_view, const auto&...){};
    //add(1, 2, vprint);

    // This works, but ugly
    const auto verb_print = [](const std::string_view msg, const auto&... args){ std::vprint_unicode(msg, std::make_format_args(args...)); };
    const auto no_print = [](const std::string_view, const auto&...){};
    if(verbose) add(2, 3, verb_print);
    else        add(2, 3, no_print);

    // This works, but tests 'verb' each call
    const auto maybe_print = [verb=verbose](const std::string_view msg, const auto&... args){ if(verb) std::vprint_unicode(msg, std::make_format_args(args...)); };
    add(3, 4, maybe_print);
}
```

Is there a way that I'm missing to obtain this assigning the functor once without testing `verbose` each time?

Comment: I don't see how you can void checking the Boolean each time since it is a runtime value.

Comment: `get_verbose_arg()` might directly return a `std::variant<verb_printer, no_printer>` and use `std::visit([](auto print){add(2, 3, print)}, get_printer_variant());`. Similar to your "ugly" method, but written differently.

Comment: I will admit CPU architecture has surpassed my understanding but I would think todays branch predictors will be able to notice `verbose` never changes and the right branch will be called correctly without overhead.

Comment: its not clear what you are looking for as answer. There are as many ways to do this as there are programmers. Each will do some detail differently, but what detail you are looking for is unclear. Also what appears "ugly" to you is another ones "beauty"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, I guess I should reformulate the question. But I disagree with the subjectivity of the "uglyness" of that repeated code, that's an objective "don't repeat yourself" violation

Comment: repetition is somewhat objective, but its not obvious that you mean that when you say "ugly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `verb_print`/`no_print` pair easier to use with a function like this:

```cpp
constexpr decltype(auto) constexpr_promote(bool x, auto&& f) {
    if (x) {
        return std::forward<decltype(f)>(f).template operator()<true>();
    } else {
        return std::forward<decltype(f)>(f).template operator()<false>();
    }
}

// ...

constexpr_promote(verbose, []<bool VERB>{
    add(3, 4, []<typename... Args>(std::format_string<Args...> msg, Args&&... args){
        if constexpr (VERB)
            std::print(msg, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    });
});
```

This is essentially the same code (there are two lambdas generated based on the two templates stamped out), but you don't need to repeat some stuff

Comment: I'm not sure how but it [works](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3aTn4395M)